# Stretch Elements Into Unknown Width Between Two Fixed-Width Elements

Tags: css, layout, overflow, tablelayout, centering

Preface: I'm not generally a UI guy, so forgive me if I have a gross misunderstanding of CSS. Please know that this question is following several hours of research/banging my head against a wall :)

Essentially what I'm trying to do is stretch an *unknown* number of elements into a space of *unknown* width, between two elements of a *known* width, all inside a container that is of variable width, centered inside the page.

I realized how crazy that all sounded as I was typing it, so let me try doing this graphically:

```
html
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   #container                                                            |
|   |-----------------------------------------------------------------|   |
|   |#header                                                          |   |
|   ||---------------------------------------------------------------||   |
|   || #logo   | #menu                                     | #social ||   |
|   ||         | |---|  |---|  |---|                 |---| |         ||   |
|   ||         | | A |  | B |  | C |  ...  ...  ...  | N | |         ||   |
|   ||         | |---|  |---|  |---|                 |---| |         ||   |
|   ||---------------------------------------------------------------||   |
|   |                                                                 |   |
|   |#body                                                            |   |
|   ||---------------------------------------------------------------||   |
|   ||                                                               ||   |
|   ||---------------------------------------------------------------||   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

where:

- `#container` is centered, and takes up 80% of the width of the document
- `#logo`, `#menu`, and `#social` are each contained in `<div/>`s
- `#logo` and `#social` have known widths; `#menu` does not
- `| A |`...`| N |` are an unknown number of `<li/>` elements within a `<ul/>`

The HTML looks like:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">Logo here</div>

            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="social"><a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Link</a></div>

        </div>
        <div id="body">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try as I might, I cannot get the `A..N` menu items to stretch across the remainder of the space between the `#logo` and the `#social` elements. They either end up smooshed together, or they take up 100% of the 80% allotted to them by the `#container`.

Some things I've already tried:

- Using `display: inline-table;` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomtheman5/MVt49/))
- Displaying `<li/>` elements inline, and giving the `#menu` element a width of 100% ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomtheman5/MVt49/2/))
- A bunch of variations on these

Things I can't/won't consider doing:

- Housing the menu items in a `<table/>`
- Any type of JavaScript approach
- Using the CSS `calc()` function

And one last note: I'm not concerned about these menu items not having enough room in the space allocated to them. However, if they do overflow, I would expect them to spill over to another line inside the `#menu` (i.e. below the `A` menu item).

There has to be a pure CSS solution to this... What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to not want to use a `<table>` element, as that it not semantic.. but that is why CSS has a set of properties built to get elements to look like table elements, while retaining their semantic meaning.

Basically, if you set a container element to `display: table;`, you can then set child elements to either `display: table-row;` or `display: table-cell;`

What does this mean for you?

Well, a set of table cells will always fill to 100% width of the parent, as well as 100% height of the parent, which is usually determined by the largest child, unless explicitly set.

So, with this in mind, if you were to set your header element `#header` to `display: table;`, you can then set `#logo`, `#nav`, and `#social` to `display: table-cell;`. Setting fixed widths on the logo and social blocks will be respected, and therefore cause the nav block to fill the remaining space.

The unordered list `ul` within the nav block can act as a second container.. once again being set to `display: table;`, allowing it's contents to fill to the full width of the nav block. Simply set the `li` elements to be `display: table-cell;` as well, and you should have the desired effect.

See this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/5RvCC/

- A nice bonus of table-cell styled elements is that they allow the `vertical-align` property, which makes vertical centring super easy, which always seems to be a common question.

Comment: I never thought to display the entire header using the table layout. This explanation makes perfect sense... Thanks so much; you're a lifesaver!